# The existence and uniqueness:

Tags: calculus, continuity

A function $N:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is called a *negation* if $N(0)=1, N(1)=0$  and $N$ is non-increasing $(x ≤ y ⇒ N(x) ≥ N(y))$. For every negation the balance point is defined $N(a)=a$. If $N$ be continuous then Would you say there is a unique balance point?(The existence and uniqueness).

Answer (score 1):

Really your question is asking if you have a function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$, with $f(0)=1$, and $f(1)=0$, does this imply there has to be a fixed point?

This is a standard exercise about continuous functions. Observe that $g(x) := f(x)-x$ has $g(0) = 1$ but also $g(1) = -1$. Thus $g$ crosses the axis. So by the intermediate value theorem, there is a point $c$ so that $g(c) = 0$. But this happens precisely when $f(c) - c = 0$ i.e. $f(c) = c$.

If your function is monotonic, there can only be one such point, as we can see from the graph that you can only cross the diagonal of the box $[0,1]^2$ once.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a balance point was shown by Alfred Yerger.

Uniqueness: Supose that $N(a)=a$ and $N(b)=b$ and that $a \ \ne b$. We can assume that $a<b$. Then we have $a=N(a) \ge N(b)=b$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks...But if N dosnt Continuous Then can we say that there is a at most a balance point?

Comment: Yes: supose that $N(a)=a$ and $N(b)=b$ and that $a \ \ne b$. We can assume that $a<b$. Then we have $a=N(a) \ge N(b)=b$, a contradiction.

Comment: Let $N(x)=1-x$ for $x \in [0,1/2)$ and $N(x)=0$ for $x \in [1/2,1]$. $N$ is not continuous, and $N(a) \ne a$ for all $a \in [0,1$]